# Building aggregation/summary reporting database against Oracle, Sql Server and Mongodb

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, mongodb, reporting, oracle11g

This is a design, since i've not done anything similar in the past, and is a good challange. I have a server which supports Oracle, Sql Server and Mongodb. You can select which one to use at startup. Essentially each server stores xml packets, which are split down into their component elements.

I need to build a reporting database which provides aggration and summary data for reports for the dashboard, but the problem (opportunity) is Mongodb. I could easily use sql server reporting services to build the reportdb, same with Oracle, or I could something like Crystal which works against both, or even create a db, and set a bundle of triggers on each table, with some pl/sql logic with Oracle, or T-Sql with Sql to create the reporting db on the fly. And that would take care of report. But their is mongodb. Little or no reporting infrastructure, certainly not outside BIRT, or jaspersoft (Java). I'm using C#.

I was thinking of having c# server component, which intercepts incoming xml packets, and extracts the appropriate element field data, and writes it into a reporting db, perhaps something like sqlite (which may be too small). If it was running on sql server, or Oracle then I would use that db instance to support the reporting db.

On any database, i'm really only supporting upto 6 months data. The data will be classified as 24 hours, 1 week, 1 month, 3 months, 6 months, with a progressive archive onto on compression and backup db.

But this is where it gets hazy. For instance, using sqlite as the reporting db, and mongodb as the xml databse. Taking an example. If a user wants to drill down, would I have to provide some kind of dynamic update that would pull the additional reporting info from Mongodb, or could all be done at the server component stage, when it's been writen in to sqlite.

Or is all f bol.cks

Any ideas or thoughts greatly appreciated.
Bob.

Comment: I need a professional to look at this.

Comment: Do you need to have an app that works and is maintained for all three options for the primary database engine, or are you going to pick one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Nucleon BI Studio](http://www.nucleonsoftware.com/Products/Nucleon-BI-Studio). You can get a fully-featured free 30 day trial, and the full version is $250. I've used it in the past, it's not bad, and a fraction of what it would cost to develop.

I am not associated with the company in any way.

Comment: I hadn't seen either, it sure gladdens my heart. Seems really cheap for a BI reporting stack. I don't think anybody has told them how cheap it is. Looks ideal. I'll check it out.

Comment: This is perfect fit. Also plan to use the MongoDB aggregation framework, as it's also a fit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of getting data from mongodb for reporting you can write your own code on top of 
1) mongodb queries
2) Aggregation framework
3) In database Map/reduce or
4) Use the hadoop connector. 
You can use the C# driver for it. Apart from that as you mentioned there is a the Jaspersoft integration or Pentaho (http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Create+a+Report+with+MongoDB)

Comment: Pentaho is expensive. Jaspersoft is java based so is out.

Comment: New aggregation framework : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework 
and tuto by Kristina Chodorow (who is on SO also): http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2012/01/26/hacking-chess-with-the-mongodb-pipeline/

Comment: @AurelienB, I hadn't seen the aggregation framework. I'll check it out.

Comment: @AurelienB, Dude, this is excellent.  Easy to call from the 10Gen c# provider, and I can genetate a state machine in stateforge to drive the aggregation workflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think Microsoft's Biztalk Server best suits your need. You can use the [pipeline component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578544.aspx) of the Biztalk server to actually process the incoming messages. (You can do simple property promotions, transformations etc.) You can use the [Biztalk Orchestrations](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/orchestration.aspx) for actual processing of the data. And for Aggregation and Reporting you can use [Biztalk's Business Activity Monitoring](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/business-activity-monitoring.aspx). It supports Real Time Aggregation of Data and puts them into your Database. It has a BAM Portal from which you can see all the stored and aggregated data. In case you want to have your own style of reports you can use [Microsoft's Report Builder 3](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460.aspx) and deploy your reports using SSRS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is a product being build, and biztalk is out.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I don't understand your question entirely but I will give it a shot: first your question, summarized.

You want to generate reports based on different types of datastores: sql this, sql that or a document database. The current options you feel you have are the build in reporting of various types.

You have various points available for getting the data. You can intercept the data as it comes into the system or derive the information from your databases. In order to make a dynamic report with drill down it really depends on the type of reporting tool you want to use. You will simply need to build a facade that hides the datastore-- either by intercepting the packets and storing them in a database of your choice or actually building them from your chosen datastore through that same abstraction/facade. You can even think of a hybrid solution where you initialize from the datastore, such as mongo, on initializing your reporting component and then update dynamically based on incoming packets.

It all depends on where you want to go.